# C++ memory allocation for a structure

Tags: c++, memory, dynamic-memory-allocation

I was given a task to create dll where I need to allocate and free memory for structure. Unfortunately, I don't know how to check if the code works.

```
#pragma once

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "RandomBlockHeader.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

namespace RandBlock {
unsigned long RandBlockFuncs::GenerateRandomBlock(RANDOM_BLOCK ** ppRandomBlock) {
    try {
        srand(time(NULL));
        ppRandomBlock = (RANDOM_BLOCK**)malloc(sizeof(RANDOM_BLOCK));
        int random = rand() % 129;
        (**ppRandomBlock).ulRandomLen = random;
        (**ppRandomBlock).pRandomData = new unsigned char[random];
        for (int i = 0; i < random; i++) {
            (**ppRandomBlock).pRandomData[i] = (char)(rand() % 256);
        }
        return 0;
    }
    catch (exception& e) {
        return -1;
    }
}

unsigned long FreeRandomBlock(RANDOM_BLOCK * pRandomBlock) {
    try {
        delete pRandomBlock;
        return 0;
    }
    catch (exception& e) {
        return -1;
    }
}
}
```

Can anybody point out where I can have possible errors? And is this a correct way to allocate memory for two pointer structure?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>    ppRandomBlock = (RANDOM_BLOCK**)malloc(sizeof(RANDOM_BLOCK));
> ```

is not good. I suspect it needs to be:

```
    *ppRandomBlock = (RANDOM_BLOCK*)malloc(sizeof(RANDOM_BLOCK));
```

Better yet, since you are using C++, change the function interface to:

```
unsigned long RandBlockFuncs::GenerateRandomBlock(RANDOM_BLOCK*&  ppRandomBlock) { ... }
```

Then, the function will look cleaner (don't use `malloc` at all):

```
unsigned long RandBlockFuncs::GenerateRandomBlock(RANDOM_BLOCK*& ppRandomBlock) {
   try {
      srand(time(NULL));
      ppRandomBlock = new RANDOM_BLOCK;
      int random = rand() % 129;
      (*ppRandomBlock).ulRandomLen = random;
      (*ppRandomBlock).pRandomData = new unsigned char[random];
      for (int i = 0; i < random; i++) {
         (*ppRandomBlock).pRandomData[i] = (char)(rand() % 256);
      }
      return 0;
   }
   catch (exception& e) {
      return -1;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that a `RANDOMBLOCK` is a `struct` type that contains (at least) two members - `ulRandomLen` which is of type `int` (not withstanding its name) and `pRandomData` which is of type pointer to `unsigned char`.

Based on those assumptions, the code has the following problems

- The function has return type of `unsigned long` and returns `-1`.   That (fortunately) has a well-defined effect - it returns the largest value an `unsigned long` can represent.   However, that may not be what the caller expects.
- The code calls `srand()` every time the function is called.  This will - unless the program runs for a very long time - reinitialise the random number seed, and result in the same sequence of random values being returned by `rand()`.   You need to ensure `srand()` is only called ONCE within the COMPLETE program, before the first call of `rand()`.
- The statement `ppRandomBlock = (RANDOM_BLOCK**)malloc(sizeof(RANDOM_BLOCK))` needs to allocate `sizeof(RANDOMBLOCK *)`, not `sizeof(RANDOM_BLOCK)`.   Better yet, replace the statement with `ppRandomBlock = new (RANDOM_BLOCK *)`, and get away from needing to worry about the sizing.
- The problem with the preceding statement (whether fixed or not) is that it does not allocate a `RANDOMBLOCK`, and leaves `*ppRandomBlock` uninitialised. This causes all the accesses via `**ppRandomBlock` to have undefined behaviour.  So, it would need to be followed by a `*ppRandomBlock = new RANDOMBLOCK`.
- The inner `for` loop has a statement `(*ppRandomBlock).pRandomData[i] = (char)(rand() % 256)` despite `pRandomData[i]` being of type `unsigned char`.   It is implementation-defined whether a straight `char` is `signed` or `unsigned`.   If it is `signed`, the maximum value a `char` can hold is not guaranteed able to hold a value greater than `127`.   That causes the conversion to `char` to have undefined behaviour.

As a partial fix, change `RANDOMBLOCK` to contain a `std::vector<unsigned char> RandomData` and eliminate the members `ulRandomLen` and `pRandomData` completely.   Then change the function to

```
unsigned long RandBlockFuncs::GenerateRandomBlock(RANDOM_BLOCK*& ppRandomBlock)
{
    try 
    {
         // assume `srand()` has been called, for example, in main()

      ppRandomBlock = new RANDOM_BLOCK;
      int random = rand() % 129;
      ppRandomBlock.RandomData.resize(random);
      for (int i = 0; i < random; i++)
      {
         ppRandomBlock.RandomData[i] = (unsigned char)(rand() % 256);
      }
      return 0;
   }
   catch (exception& e)
   {
       return -1;
   }
}
```

Note that the above does not fix the problem with an `unsigned` return type and `-1` return value.

More generally, the overarching problem in the OP's code is that it is a rough translation of some C code - with adornment - into C++.   Even if it was good C code, good C technique is not always good C++ technique and vice versa.   And, on the face of it, the original code involved bad technique in C.

It would be better to rewrite the code completely to use C++ library features (I've demonstrated one element of that, more are possible) and not use operator `new` directly at all.